# How does the virualbox manage network connections of the hosted OS

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, network-shares

[I'm new to Linux and virtualbox so this one is probably pretty simple]

I've installed virtualbox on my Win10, created a VM and installed Ubuntu (18) on it. Afterwards, I've created a shared folder on the Ubuntu hosted machine.

How can I access the Ubuntu machine shared folder from the Win10?
More generally, how is the IP of the VM is managed, is it a LAN with the hosting win10? and can I configure/manage this LAN?

Comment: The question is too broad. Read the VirtualBox docs https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html

Comment: There is a very specific question and a broad one. D'Be nice to have at least an answer to the specific park - how to access the shared folder on the ubuntu machine from the host.

Comment: See this https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

Comment: Tx, but the link above suggests access from the vm to a shared folder on the host. What I needed is the other way around. Access a folder shared by the vm, from the host